# React context does not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm using React 16.6 and my goal is to save user information in context.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Axios from 'axios';

import './assets/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './assets/css/main.css';

import Default from './default';
import Login from './login';
import PrivateRoute from './private-route';

import UserInfo from './user-info';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            user: {}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token) {
            Axios.get('/getuser', {
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
                }
            }).then(res => {
                if (res.data) {
                    this.setState({ user: res.data });
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('err login: ', err);
                localStorage.clear();
                // delete storage
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.user);
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <UserInfo.Provider value={this.state.user}>
                        <Route exact path="/login/:token" component={Login} />
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Default} />
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/protected" component={() => <div>Protected</div>} />
                    </UserInfo.Provider>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The problem is that the context wont update when the axios returns data and updates the state. state does update but context does not.

This is console log:

> {}
>
> {}
>
> {id: 1, personaName: "majid", …}

Comment: I'm positive the context is updated. These are child components that may not be updated. It's not shown where it's not updated. The question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Could be this issue https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5901 if deps are old enough or something else.

Comment: how are you checking that the context is not updated ? because it seems that it should get re-render and re-populated because the console log shows data !

Answer (score 0):

Let's use some trick, don't render anything until response isn't come!!

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            user: {},
            mounted: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token) {
            Axios.get('/getuser', {
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
                }
            }).then(res => {
                if (res.data) {
                    this.setState({ user: res.data, mounted: true });
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('err login: ', err);
                localStorage.clear();
                // delete storage
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.mounted) {
          return <div>Loading...</div>
        }

        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <UserInfo.Provider value={this.state.user}>
                        <Route exact path="/login/:token" component={Login} />
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Default} />
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/protected" component={() => <div>Protected</div>} />
                    </UserInfo.Provider>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: oh no, dont do this, it makes the component more complex without any reason :(

Comment: @LinoRabolini can you explain me why?

Comment: Yes, 
1. This may solve his problem but it is not a real fix, it is just a patch to his situation
2. The mounted flag doesn't reflect the real mounted state, it reflects if the axios response was successful.
3. This adds an extra state prop that he doesn't need at all

Comment: and then what is a real fix?

Comment: you can't give a real fix until you have all the information about the issue. For what he is writing, the context should be updating. Maybe there is an issue in the way he is checking for that context value. Or an issue regarding the moment where he is checking for that context value.